# Panel scroll bar not working in HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap HTML 5 and I have a panel inside which a table is present. I have enabled scroll for the panel but the table is not adjusting with the panel and the scroll bar is visible but inactive. I want the table inside the panel and each head content should be present within the cell (no overlapping) and the scroll bar needs to be active when content is spacious and effective.

The HTML is as,

```
        <div class="panel-body panel-scroll">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableMyCert">
                <thead style="background-color:lightblue">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-sm-4">head 1</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-3">head 2</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-3">head 3</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-3">head 4</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-3">head 5</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-5">head 6</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-2">head 7</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-5">head 8</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-4">head 9</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-2">head 10</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-5">head 11</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-4">head 12</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-2">head 13</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-5">head 14</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-4">head 15</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-2">head 16</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-5">head 17</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-5">head 18</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

and the CSS is as,

```
.panel-scroll{
overflow-x:scroll;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: No need to use scrollbar since  table is  self responsive in bootstrap, you need to make that structure

Comment: Can you provide some picture/design about the expected behaviour? Get confused with your question description...

Comment: @this.girish I dont really understand that. the table heading is just gettign overlapped with the border and even goes to the next cell content. not sure why.

Comment: I'm not sure what the desired effect is? Here's a bootply to get you started, perhaps help us understand what you're expecting. http://www.bootply.com/lFQUiQrz4T 
What's also part of the confusion for me is why you're using Bootstrap cols in the TH elements, what do you think is going to happen?

Answer (score 0):

make structre like this

```
<div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableMyCert">
  //rest of your code
    </table>
     </div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableMyCert">
                    <thead style="background-color:lightblue">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-sm-4">head 1</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-3">head 2</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-3">head 3</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-3">head 4</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-3">head 5</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-5">head 6</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-2">head 7</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-5">head 8</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-4">head 9</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-2">head 10</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-5">head 11</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-4">head 12</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-2">head 13</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-5">head 14</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-4">head 15</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-2">head 16</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-5">head 17</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-5">head 18</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
    
    
      </div>
```

Comment: you mean I should remove the panel??

Comment: you can add table inside anything you want ,what i'm saying is no need to use scroll something css remove that, bootstrap provides you core responsiveness. copy above code will resolve your issue and also run this snippet by clicking "run code snippet" you will understand more